# Profile page layout bug

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

[phwd](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/40/phwd)’s profile page layout has a bug, as seen below:

[image]

Tested in Safari, Chrome and Firefox, on Mac.

Comment: This (with a different user) has been [reported on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316111), too. It's a network-wide problem with a few user's pages. We'll look into it. Thanks!